# Drag all measure values from SSAS cube pivot table

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table

I have multiple grouped measures. ie PL, Expense, Revenue etc. They all contain a lot of measures of around 15+ measures. When building a report from the cubes. The users usually have to drop the measures one by one into the pivot table. Is there a quick way to just drop the whole group into the pivot? ie show all 15 measures of PL in one go? (as opposed to clicking 15 measures and putting it in one by one.
Thanks, gemmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what tool you are using to view the cube.  In SQL Server Management Studio, you are able to drag the entire list of measures across in one go (but not individual measure groups)

In Excel, however you are limited to single measures at a time.  You can "Defer Layout Update" so that a refresh does not take place between each measure selection, which will help your end users speed up multiple measure selections